# XSLT xsl:when cuts off rest of the XML

Tags: xml, xslt

My XSL and XML can be found [here](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuNZ).

The problem is probably something in this part:

```
            <xsl:when test="property/property[@name='text_key' and value = 'presentation' and ../property[@name='text_value']]">
                <property>
                    <property name="text_value">
                        <value><xsl:value-of select="property" /> <xsl:call-template name="special" /></value>
                    </property>
                </property>
            </xsl:when>
```

It causes the rest of the XML cut off after applying the "add this text" text. What I would like is to get all other property elements after that as well in the finished XML. The goal is simply append "add this text" to the presentation property.

Comment: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net is great, there is no doubt, but you should really include your XML / XSLT (ideally reduced in size) in your question too, just in case that website goes down. Thank you!

Comment: I tried my best but the Stack Overflow wouldn't let me post that much code.

Comment: There is no need to post that much code - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you simply want to write additional templates for those `property` or `value` elements you want to change e.g. like

```
<xsl:param name="special">add this text</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="property[@name = 'itemgroup']/value">
    <xsl:copy>new itemgroup</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="property[property[@name='text_key' and value = 'presentation']]/property[@name = 'text_value']/value">
    <value><xsl:value-of select="concat(., $special)"/></value>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuNZ/1 has the full example. For the `concat(., $special)` I am not quite sure whether the `.` is right but I couldn't tell from all the nested `property` which value you want to output.